# Making for loops faster in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have an application in which I need to run the algorithm for every unique value of partitioning column (KEY) in dataframe df. The slice of df is stored in df2. And the inner function (do_calc) needs to run in serial as in order to calculate row i, I need to use the previous rows. However to speed up things, the algorithm can be run in parallel for different values of KEY column.  I have tried using  prange from numba but that was resulting in segmentation faults.

I was wondering if there is a better way to speed up the loops below?

```
import pandas as pd


def do_bcf(x,df):
    lam_e = x[0] #smoothing weight for forecast error 
    lam_a = x[1] #smoothing weight for demand level
    lam_s = x[2] #smoothing weight for weekly seasonality
    clip_factor = x[3]
    key_col = 'KEY'
    list_key_cols = df[key_col].unique()
    df_calibrate = pd.DataFrame()
    for j in list_key_cols:
        df2 = df[df[key_col]==j].reset_index()
        for i in range(init_period,len(df2)):
            df2 = do_calc(df2, i,  lam_e, lam_a, lam_s, clip_factor)
        df_calibrate = pd.concat([df_calibrate,df2])
    return df_calibrate
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try making a copy of the slice (`df2`).  I've done something similar, and copying my slices made a surprisingly significant improvement to performance.  (I can't tell you for certain whether or not it will help since you don't show the definition of `do_calc`.) 
 http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: Hello do you mean in this way?

`df2 = do_calc(df2.copy(), i,  lam_e, lam_a, lam_s, clip_factor)`

Also can you suggest a way to run outer loop in parallel? Thank you.